# writeFile Asynchronous. Does not seem to work in a module

Tags: javascript, discord

Bot used to work flawlessly but I thought it would be good to split my code since it was getting too large. I've fixed most of the mistakes that pop up but however I could not. for the life of me, get the called modules to write to file. The modules seem to have a cached values if it's like a counter (like in the slots game I made), however something like profile would still show the value in the stored values in the json file, unaffected by the game (although the count in the game is changing). When I reset the bot, the value in the game reverts back to the value on the json, so I'm assuming the fs.writeFile I placed in the module isn't successful n the module is only rendering a temporary cache.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const fs = require("fs"); 
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./points.json", "utf8"));
let extrasettings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./extra.json", "utf8"));
let tempgamefiles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./temporarygamefiles.json", "utf8"));
module.exports = (bot, message, args) => {
  // asynchronous method of writing to file, however not really working
  fs.writeFile("./extra.json", JSON.stringify(extrasettings), (err) => {if (err) console.error(err)});
}
```

file path is correct and the exact code used to work fine in 1 single ginormous file.. don't know how moduling would break it.

Comment: What's `fs.writefs` ?

Comment: fs.writefile* i mistyped it into stackoverflow, code has line: fs.writeFile("./extra.json", JSON.stringify(extrasettings), (err) => {if (err) console.error(err)});

Comment: If you're not getting an error and nor is your file being updated, then there's something else in your code that's preventing. Look for conditions and `return`.